# Using associations with counter cache when there's already a counter with no nested data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I imported a db schema and its content from a legacy site into a Rails project.

I have DVDs and votes. Votes are simply an integer field in Dvd model like `Dvd.votes:integer=10`.

Since I can also associate new votes to users easily in Rails, I created a new `Vote` model that belongs to `Dvd` and `User` models.

My situation is that now when calling `Dvd.first.votes` I get an empty array [] since there's no data yet on the Vote model but the `votes_count` still has the imported counts.

(I also renamed the `Dvd.votes` field to `Dvd.votes_count` after adding the `Vote` model and added `belongs_to :dvd, :counter_cache => true` on Vote model.)

I'm not sure what would be the ideal solution to this problem. Should I call votes by simply querying `Dvd.votes_count` or there's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it might be not an answer for your question, but instead of creating your own solution I recommend to use gem: https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up
which already optimized. In your situation it may save a lot of time.
So you need to install gem and then import existing votes to it.